# Appgyver Steroids Ionic Keyboard Bug

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins, steroids

I have been building a simple IOS application user the Appgyver Steroids framework. All was going well but I have started getting a random error message appear. It happens on the first view where there is a form with a few inputs. As soon as you click any of them this error will sometimes pop up:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'cordova.plugins.Keyboard')
```

The reason I describe it as random is because it doesn't always appear and other times I get one to three alerts pop up in succession.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not a solution as such. I just removed the 'onerror' javascript file to hide the issue as it wasn't affecting the application and I couldn't find any answers.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.  I've built a sandbox that reproduces the issue and have submitted it to Appgyver, so hopefully it makes it onto their radar.

Comment: No problem. I'll be interested in hearing the outcome if you get an answer.